# Led matrix 64x64 1/32s HUB75 with only A, B and NC lines

Tags: led-matrix, dot-matrix-display

I am trying to drive a led matrix, a RGB 64x64 with a HUB75 connector, 1/32 scan, with 2 RGB lines (R1G1B1, R2G2B2), a latch pin, a clock pin, an output enabled pin, and 3 pins I don't know how to use it : A, B, NC

Image : 
[image] (also [here](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/13116908/14502166/40feb680-01aa-11e6-8041-b4d814c6badb.JPG))

Beside the A, B and NC lines, all other lines (RGB, clock, strobe, OE) behave like other "classical" HUB75 panels.

Does anyone have managed to drive a panel like mine ?

Comment: NC == not connected - it likely does nothing

Comment: Also this thread answers your questions if you read it to the end https://twitter.com/andrewmiskelly/status/962612754170331137

Answer (score -2):

See https://github.com/hzeller/rpi-rgb-led-matrix/issues/120

Apparently there is concern that github might fall off the face of the earth, so hopefully this intro can pass muster...  There is a *lot* more detail in that linked thread than I can summarize adequately, but I think these are the important bits:

> do you think that the pannel may be driven this way :
>
> Display bottom line (32th) send 1 line of data (RGB+Clock) x64, strobe
>   A, up B, strobe A x31, down B strobe latch Display previous line up B,
>   strobe A, down B send 1 line of data (RGB+Clock) x64, strobe A, up B,
>   strobe A x30, down B ... and scan all 32 lines ?

and

> I think the roles of pins : A : strobing pushes display one row down.
>   B : down, pushed row (by A strobe) is lit, down pushed row is black.
>   Clocking data set it on all rows. So for each scan, I clock the data,
>   and push only one lit row (with A and B). So I push down first row as
>   lit, and the remainings as black, so the "lit" row moves down.

There are code samples in there for driving a panel with an RPi.  Timing is apparently also important but it's possible that I'm misreading exactly how, and I have not had time to really study it.  I'm working on an FPGA panel driver but back-burnering implementing this feature for now.

Comment: Hi, I figured out how it works, and I worked with hzeller to make his lib compatible with my kind of panel. He has patched his code, I still have to test it (no free spare time yet).